# openai api key automatically rotating when deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openai-api, api-key

I'm building a web page using openai gpt API in reactjs. I saved my API key on .env file then gitignored it. And I deployed my code with gh-pages, but openai detects it and rotate the key automatically. How can I use API key properly?

```
const DEFAULT_PARAMS = {
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages: [{"role": "user",
                        "content": message
            }],
            temperature: 1,
            max_tokens: 1000
        };
        const params_ = {...DEFAULT_PARAMS};
        const result = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + String(process.env.REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY)
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(params_)
        });
        const data = await result.json()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64761011/access-github-pages-secret-api-keys-via-javascript-or-include-in-html-mark-up) regarding securing secrets on static websites hosted on GitHub Pages.

Short answer: it's impossible because everything is exposed in the code.

You need to use another way to deploy your website.
For example, frameworks like [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I use nestjs framework, the apiKey also rotated..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeDgk.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First encrypt the API key using `crypto-js`:

```js
const encryptText = (plainText: string): string => {
  return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, secretKey).toString();
};
```

Then copy the results and remove the above code. Next, do this in the file where the API key is needed:

```js
const decryptText = (encryptedText: string): string => {
  const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedText, "your password");
  return bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
};
```

And you can use the authorization like so:

```js
Authorization: `Bearer ${ decryptText(encryptedAPI)}`
```